# Reading CSV file into Octave and accessing columns

Tags: csv, octave

I am reading in a CSV file in the following format:

```
 N,X,Y,Z
```

Eventually, I want to:

```
 plot(N,X,B,Y,N,Z)
```

First, I have to read the data in, which I have:

```
 reshape(csv2cell('file.csv',',',1,0),DIMx,DIMy)
```

I know that:

```
 N = [*,1]
 X = [*,2]
 Y = [*,3]
 Z = [*,4]
```

How do I take the slices and put them into their own separate array, so that I can plot?

Comment: This is basic indexing. See [the documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.0/Index-Expressions.html) to learn how to do this.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have read over that document, it is not of much help.

Comment: ahh yes ok, i was excluding the , and it was spitting garbage back at me. thanks!

Comment: @CrisLuengo Why is the linked document "shitty"? Are you able to improve it? If yes then please go ahead and provide a patch.

Comment: @Andy: Sorry for being derisive. It's a lot easier to find fault than to improve those faults. Being a critic is easy. --- Compare to the MATLAB docs linked. They put a **lot** of money into documentation. It's hard for a volunteer-driven project to accomplish the same quality, depth and completeness. Especially if those volunteers are programmers and not writers/educators. --- I really appreciate you encouraging action over criticism.